How to use Doxygen-Autolink comfortably with C++ namespaces?
I am searching for a possibility to reduce the need for writing down the namespaces for a class-reference in .dox and .md-files ("custom pages") used by doxygen. Since this is really annoying and time-consuming and developers do not want to write that much.
The documentation in doxygen (https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html) states:
"All words in the documentation that correspond to a documented class and contain at least one non-lower case character will automatically be replaced by a link to the page containing the documentation of the class." This is only partly true, since if the class is in a namespace this won't work. I am feeling pretty dumb but I didn't find any other possibility than refering to such classes with the full namespace.
So let's assume we have a class:
namespace first
{
namespace second
{
namespace third
{
  /**
  * @brief This is my class
  */
  class MyClass : public BaseClass
  {

  }
}
}
}

now the autolinking by writing just "MyClass" in doxygen won't work. We need to write ::first::second::third::MyClass to reference this class.
E.g.:
This is a markdown-file which needs to reference ::first::second::third::MyClass but wants to reference only MyClass via autolinking

Is there a possibility to get rid of the namespaces? I understand that this makes totally sense, especially if you have multiple classes with the same name in different namespaces.
But we are also restructuring our documentation, so we would add markdown-files exactly where the source-code is placed. The markdown-referencing works the same as in the doxygen file in this case, so we would not distinguish here.
But since the file is now located exactly in this folder, which also only contains the class in this namespace, I would like to somehow create a setting that doxygen does not need those namespaces or that it will only check the source-files in the folder where the referencing .dox/.md-file is located. I also checked if I can somehow define some kind of substitute for namespaces but didn't find any possibility.
So to illustrate my goal: Instead of
"You can use ::first::second::third::MyClass in a restricted way. Since you derived from ::first::second::third::BaseClass, ::first::second::third::MyClass will contain already the functionality to make it a ::first::second::third::YourClass"
I want to have smth like:
"You can use MyClass in a restricted way. Since you derived from BaseClass, MyClass will contain already the functionality to make it a YourClass"
I can guess no developer, except myself, going through the pain and writing down all the namespaces again and again. Not only is it annoying, it's also not really readable and the namespaces would be shown anyway when you click on the class.
And if you don't do it that way, then you need to search manually for this class.
So how can I get rid of this?

Which version of doxygen are you using? Where do you want to use the autolinking (example)?

@albert I am using the 1.10.0 under Ubuntu, WSL2. The autolinking should be used inside a .dox and .md-file, so a custom page. I think that I added an example. Not sure how I can make it more clear. Maybe I need to ask: what's unclear? So it's about those namespaces of C++ which always need to be mentioned.

I don't see a possibility in the current doxygen version, one would like to have some sort of \scope command where one can define the scope that (also) should be used for autolinking. Direct linking based on the directory content is not a good idea (when the original code is reorganized or the file is also use in a doxygen \include or \snippet statement from another directory this might all lead to problems).

@albert yes that's right, also if you reference a class outside the namespace you would need to add this namespace anyway. so we can drop this approach as well.
